# How to wait a task after cloning VM with VMWare.vim.dll?

Tags: c#, vmware, powercli

I am working on a web interface which manage virtual machines on vsphere Esx 5.5. My program is developed with .net web forms (not MVC).

I followed jeffpaton posts (using VMware.Vim  ) which helped me (Thanks to you, Jeff) https://communities.vmware.com/thread/434579.

But now i freeze on this subject. I do not know how to wait a task after cloning VM. My web site launch vsphere command to the Vsphere Esx with vmware.vim. I need to know when vpshere finished his work to launch an another instruction.

I try to use PropertyCollector but i do not know how to use it :

i red this post but without success :

Here is a part of my code with a try but i am blocked. i use jeffpaton functions.

```
using VMware.Vim;
...
VimClient client;
string serverUrl = "..."
client.Connect("https://" + serverUrl + "/sdk");
client.Login(userLogin, userPassword);
...
ManagedObjectReference cloneTask_MoRef = null;

//1 waiting the cloning task
cloneTask_MoRef = sourceVm.cloneVM_Task(sourceVm.Parent, "cloneName", mySpec);

if (cloneTask_MoRef == null) {
 //error
}else
{
    PropertyCollector pc = new PropertyCollector(client, cloneTask_MoRef);

    PropertyFilterSpec[] pfs = null;
    RetrieveOptions ro = new RetrieveOptions();
    RetrieveResult rResult = new RetrieveResult();


    //PropertySpec
    //pc.CreateFilter(pfs, true);
    //rResult = pc.RetrievePropertiesEx(pfs,ro);
    //

   //2 PowerOn the CloneVM                                                       
   cloneVM = this.vimClientTools.getVirtualMachines(selectedDC, cloneName)[0];

   //3 waiting the powerOn Task...

      //What could i do to know if the task is over or in progress ? :-(
```

I need some help. if somebody has a suggestion beginning...

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably too late, but here goes.

VimClient has a WaitForTask method;

```
client.WaitForTask(cloneTask_MoRef);
```

Alternatively, you could get the task and view its progress;

```
var task = (Task) client.GetView(cloneTask_MoRef, null);

while (task.Info.State != TaskInfoState.success)
{
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    task.UpdateViewData();
    if (task.Info.State == TaskInfoState.error)
        throw new Exception($"The clone failed: {task.Info.Error.LocalizedMessage}");

    Console.WriteLine(task.Info.Progress);
}
```